# Loop through json ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to create a loop from the json data of an ajax respone. The json returned is:

```
{
    status: "ok",
    count: 2,
    count_total: 2,
    pages: 1,
    posts: [
        {
            id: 19,
            content: "<p>Dektop Test 2</p> ",
        },
        {
            id: 11,
            content: "<p>Desktop Test</p> ",
        }
    ]
}
```

I using the following code to convert the json data into html markup, my problem is getting a loop going. I would like to output markup for each instance of data

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $.getJSON('theurlforjson')
        .success(function(response) {

            var $title = $('.content').html(response.posts[0].content);

        });
});
</script>

<div class="content"></div>
```

You can see the the json data for .posts[0].content is loaded into .content, I would like some help creating a loop with the scenario

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
for( var post in response.posts ){
    $('.content').append( response.posts[post].content );
}
```

Check out the [MDN Article on the for..in syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). And caching the `$('.content')` selector in a variable will improve the performance.

Comment: nice, and anyway of making a container div for each with the post id? Just looking for a nudge in the right direction

Comment: If you wanted a new container for every post you could create the new container: `$('<div/>', { id: 'post-' + response.posts[post].id, html: response.posts[post].content }).appendTo('body');`

Comment: still a bit confused where I put this?

Comment: That would go inside the `for` loop replacing the `$('.content').append(...`